# Syntax error after encoding a script in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption, encoding, decoding

I'm studying crypting methods and I'm using `NXCrypt`, I found it on [github](https://github.com/Hadi999/NXcrypt)
After encoding a script of mine with `NXcrypt`, and after starting my script with `python3`, terminal raises:

```
File "encryptscript.py", line 1
SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\xf3' in file encryptscript.py on line 1, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
```

Or:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Or if I run with `./` instead of using python:

```
...
...
./encryptedscript.py: 3: ./encryptedscript.py: �: not found
./encryptedscript.py: 4: ./encryptedscript.py: Yc@sdZddlZddlZddlZddlZddlZddlZddZ: not found
...
continues
```

What I tried was writing this line:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

but it doesn't work anyway.

A part of encrypted code:

```
^C�
^UI|Yc^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^T^@^@^@@^@^@^@s^F^B^@^@d^@^@Z^@^@d^A^@d^B^@l^A^@Z^A^@d^A$
^@Z
^@d^A^@d^B^@l^K^@Z^K^@d^A^@d^B^@l^L^@a^L^@d^A^@d
```

Comment: Show us the code.

Comment: done it________

Comment: Don't you see the problem?

Comment: no... I'm a newbie sorry, could you tell me?

Comment: Your code is not written in English.

Comment: If the encrypted bytecode is bytecode, you should make it a `.pyc`. Else python cannot differentiate.

Comment: how can I? just renaming it?

Comment: My initial impression is that you have not properly considered "crypting methods" [sic] and neither has the author of NXcrypt, which feels a lot more like a joke or red herring than any relevant tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've run the NXcrypt program, you've demonstrated a dangerous lack of consideration about security, and quite possibly destroyed your own work.

First sign of malice: while it's unclear what NXcrypt is actually supposed to do, all its key phrases are indicators of subterfuge at best: encryption, suspicious activity, backdoors, etc. The only possible excuse for requiring superuser permission is to alter your system itself; this was supposed to access a script, of all things.

First sign of incompetence: The description of what it does is technically impossible. Output being "fully undetectable" can only mean it doesn't exist. There's no logical reason it would need root. A backdoor is at best only useful to those who know how to access it, and this has no hints about structure of either input file. There's a "tutorial video" which at this point I fully expect to be a rick-roll. The checksum comparisons say nothing but that data is different.

A quick glance inside the script, and most of the variables are randomly named, reinforcing the impression the whole program is an act of trolling. A sign of sloppiness at best is that all the code is unstructured toplevel. They refer to bytecode compilation as "encryption" (which it is not). [CPython's compiled bytecode](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/200804/the_structure_of_pyc_files.html) is different with every release, so the whole antivirus detection description is a red herring at best; this is not a usable distribution format. It is also not an encrypted format at all; all the "junk" data does nothing but pad the file, at best.

Early on, the program does a Linux specific test demanding to be run as root. Nothing in the program has a sane reason to be run as root (or at all).

The program starts out by overwriting its input file, which is usually a terrible idea. After bytecompiling it, it uses a platform specific external command to rename it to the target filename, and the particular commands have different effects; besides which, there's a standard library function for that task.

In the "injection mode", the program tries to take two files and put them as bodies to two distinct functions, then make a script which starts both as distinct threads. It's a terrible idea much like the rest of the script, also very obvious as a signature, and if it ever works a testament to the effectiveness of Python's namespace scoping.

---

Conclusion: The program in question is useless and dangerous. It demonstrates a very poor understanding of what CPython does, poor skill in programming, and intent of creating malware. At best, it's a piece of junk trolling script kiddies.